# Spring Security - Remember me cookie doesn't survive restart

Tags: spring-security, spring-session, remember-me

I have a spring boot application (2.1.6) with spring security.
I added a capability of "remember me", but unfortunatelly - after server restart the app doesn't remember the user.

my configuration looks like this:

```
.and().rememberMe().key("*****").tokenValiditySeconds(15768000)
```

I debug `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` , and I saw there is a signature that doesn't much between the cookie and the calculation after restart.
The reason the signatures are different is because they are based on passwords, and the passwords are retrieved differently between setting the remember me cookie and reading the cookie.
I'm not sure why.

All my users are defined in-memory:

```
authBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("david")
.password("{noop}mypassword").authorities("ROLE_USER")
```

Can you please help me understand why the remember me doesn't survive server restarts?

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116854/remember-me-cookie-deleted-after-app-restart-is-this-ok

Comment: Nop. It refers to a different problem